# Что делать с "Новым миром", противопоставленным "старому"?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Именно из-за разницы трактовок, которые дают крупнейшие эксперты в
>   области истории искусства данного периода, становится очевидным, что
>   искусство IV века всё ещё пробует живописать **Новый мир** средствами
>   **старого**.

Comment: Что это за понятие такое *Новый мир* со заглавной буквы?

Comment: Не могу знать, так в тексте... Я, будь автором, закурсивила бы *новый мир* - и все дела, без прописных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если слова немного переставить:

Именно из-за разницы трактовок, которые дают крупнейшие эксперты в области истории искусства данного периода, становится очевидным, что искусство IV века всё ещё пробует **живописать Новый мир старыми средствами.**

"Новый мир"  оформлен как имя собственное,  а "старый мир" – это скорее нарицательное понятие, вместе они не смотрятся

Comment: Автор доотмечает Старый Новый Год - пусть разберётся сам: я все ответы с комментами ему отсылаю.

Answer (score 1):

В искусствоведческих и литературоведческих текстах я встречала только противопоставление ***нового мира старому*** (со строчной буквы и без кавычек).

«Я не знаю в новейшем искусстве никого, в ком был бы такой исступленный творческий порыв, разрушающий **старый мир** и созидающий **мир новый**".

"Живопись из чисто красочной стихии должна воссоздать **новый мир**, совершенно непохожий на весь природный мир. <   ˃ Футуризм по своему чувству жизни и по своему сознанию совсем не радикален, он—лишь переходное состояние, более конец **старого мира**, чем начало **нового**". Бердяев Н.А. Кризис искусства. http://www.odinblago.ru/krizis_iskusstva

"С.В. Малютин показывает человека **старого мира**, сумевшего вписаться в **новый мир**". http://www.artimex.ru/sovetskaya-i-postsovetskaya-zhivopis-01

"Петров-Водкин трактовал новую эпоху в контексте новой судьбы России, но своим творчеством не стремился до основания уничтожить весь **старый мир** и на его руинах возвести **новый**". https://www.buro247.ru/culture/arts/10-nov-2017-art-of-revolution.html

Дмитриевская Л.Н. Образы **старого и нового мира**. Пейзаж в романе Е.Замятина «Мы» // Искусство в школе, № 1, 2010, с.28–31. http://www.mirfilologa.ru/articles/ruslit/20vek/58-obrazy-starogo-i-novogo-mira-pejzazh-v-romane-ezamyatina-qmyq

Авторы школьных учебников пишут об изображении **старого и нового мира** в поэме А.Блока «Двенадцать».

А вот в учении «Агни Йога» говорится о **Новом и Старом Мире**, но непоследовательно (возможно, это зависит не столько от оттенков лексического значения слов, сколько от качества перевода).
"Старый мир ютится во всех частях света, так же Новый Мир нарождается всюду вне границ и условий".
"Старый и Новый Мир отличаются в сознании, но не во внешних признаках".
"Возраст и условия не имеют значения. Красные знамёна часто подымаются руками старого мира, полными предрассудков".
"Именно, делите мир не по северу и по югу, не по западу и востоку, но всюду различайте старый мир от Нового".
http://nfo-mir.com/lectures/filosof/item/1461-novyj-mir-rossiya-yavit